# Ошибка при импортировании OpenCV-python ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, opencv, python-import

Стоит система ubuntu 16.04 LTS с собранным python3.9 (НЕ ЧЕРЕЗ APT)

Когда я пытаюсь импортировать библиотеку OPENCV у меня выдаётся ошибка:

```
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/../opencv_python_headless.libs/libpng16-186fce2e.so.16.37.0)
```

Как её исправить?

Comment: Похоже что у вас библиотека zlib не установлена, она требуется для работы libpng, которая в свою очередь требуется для работы opencv.

Comment: используйте стандартный питон и стандартную библиотеку opencv из репозитория своей ubuntu.  у вас же конфликт бинарных библиотек, даже если они есть, ими opencv не может воспользоваться. см. ваши ошибки при выполнении.

Comment: А какие команды для установки нужно вводить?

Comment: Я не устанавливал Python с оффицального репозитория

Comment: вам следует прочитать написанное - "установить из репозитория официальный питон и opencv".  например, поискать и найти подобную статью https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html

Comment: на будущее, если какой-либо питоновский фреймворк написан на питоне, можете его ставить через pip3 не боясь. но если есть доступ к бинарникам из сторонних библиотек (как opencv, ffmpeg, postgres и т.п.), то следует ставить только пакеты из официального репозитория, то есть только через apt install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполни команды

```
pip install zlib numpy
pip install opencv-python==4.5.5.64
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали, чем это поможет